# Get all enabled languages for a CRM organisation

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

A simple question that I have not found an answer for.
In Dynamics CRM 2013 (or any other version for that matter), is there a way to programmatically retrieve a list of all enabled languages in an organisation?

It's easy to get the base/default language by querying the *languagecode* field in the *organization* entity.
But how can I get all the other languages?

My application is in C# and is external to CRM so no JavaScript please. This should be served by the web services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [RetrieveProvisionedLanguagesRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrieveprovisionedlanguagesrequest.aspx) to retrieve all languages that are enabled for the organization you are connected to:

```
var req = new RetrieveProvisionedLanguagesRequest();
var res = (RetrieveProvisionedLanguagesResponse)service.Execute(req);
```

Here `res.RetrieveProvisionedLanguages` is an [int array of locale ID values that represent the provisioned languages.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrieveprovisionedlanguagesresponse.retrieveprovisionedlanguages.aspx)

Comment: Ah yes, the Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages namespace which I always ignore due to it not being an Xrm one.